# Can't receive UNICAST packet over WiFi using INADDR_ANY

Tags: c++, winsock2

I have a device broadcasting over ethernet, using the code below this successfully receives the packets.  The device also unicasts the same packet over WiFi but this is not received (Disabling all other interfaces except WiFi in windows I get a timeout error).  If I change:

```
address.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
```

to

```
address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.0.13");
```

Which is the address of the wifi interface it does receive the packets.  The packets over both ethernet and WiFi can be seen in WireShark, the only difference between them are the destination addresses (broadcast and unicast) and the ttl.

Here is the code:

```
int main()
{
    int iResult;
    char recv_buf[4000];
    int opt = 1;
    WORD wVersionRequested;
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int err;

    wVersionRequested = MAKEWORD(2, 2);

    err = WSAStartup(wVersionRequested, &wsaData);
    if (err != 0) {
        printf("WSAStartup failed with error: %d\n", err);
        return 1;
    }

    SOCKET handle = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP);

    int return_code = 0;

    return_code = setsockopt(handle, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, reinterpret_cast<char *>(&opt), sizeof(opt));

    std::cout<<"socket option 1 return:" << return_code << std::endl;

    DWORD tv = 100;
    return_code = setsockopt(handle, SOL_SOCKET, SO_RCVTIMEO, reinterpret_cast<char *>(&tv), sizeof(tv));

    std::cout << "socket option 2 return:" << return_code<< std::endl;

    sockaddr_in address;
    address.sin_family = AF_INET;
    address.sin_port = htons(3000);
    address.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    //address.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("192.168.0.13"); //this works
    memset(&address.sin_zero, 0, sizeof(address.sin_zero));

    std::cout << "bind return:" <<  bind(handle, (const sockaddr *)&address, sizeof(sockaddr_in)) << std::endl;

    // Receive data until the server closes the connection
    do {
        Sleep(5000);
        iResult = recv(handle, recv_buf, 4000, 0);
        if (iResult > 0)
            printf("Bytes received: %d\n", iResult);
        else if (iResult == 0)
            printf("Connection closed\n");
        else
            printf("recv failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
    } while (true);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: **Q1**: Is the IP 192.168.0.13 the address of the server or the client?  
**Q2**: Is this program running on the server or the client?

Comment: @YSC it is the address of the client.  This code is running on the client.  All I know about the server is it sends packets over port 3000.

Comment: And how is the client supposed to get the server's address if you provide it with INADDR_ANY?

Comment: A client is supposed to know the ip of the server it connects to.

Comment: @YSC I am using UDP so there is no connection.  In this case I don't think the client needs to know the server IP?

Comment: Ok. **HUGE** misconception here. Yes there's connection with UDP, but a stateless connection with oposition to TCP's stateful connection.

Comment: @YSC Everywhere I read (including Wikipedia) calls UDP connectionless.  Anyway I think it's semantics.  What are you suggesting I should do?  Call connect(..)?  Use recvfrom()?

Comment: @YSC is wrong. UDP is a connectionless protocol. There is a connect *operation* in the API, but it isn't part of the protocol. **But** the sender needs to know the address of the receiver,

Comment: Wrong nomenclature on my part. From the point of view of osi layers 4&5 that's true UDP is connectionless. Same conclusion though, the client needs the server's addr.